# How can I simultaneously persist new entries on both sides of a ManyToMany relationship in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to persist the following objects:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class Item {
    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "item_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_name")
    )
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Tag {
    ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

The behaviour I expect is that when saving a new Item that has a new Tag, the Item will cascade the persist operation to the new Tag and insert them into their respective tables as well as the corresponding entry in the join table. However, the transaction fails because Hibernate tries inserting into the Item table, followed immediately by the join table which has a foreign key constraint on the not-yet-inserted Tag. The strange thing is that when I update the `CascadeType` of my Item to `CascadeType.ALL`, it inserts the Item, the Tag, and updates the join table in the manner I desire. This is not the case even if I include all `CascadeType`s except for `CascadeType.REMOVE`.

Obviously this is not a realistic solution for me as I do not want Tags deleted when I remove an Item, so 1) why does `CascadeType.ALL` produce such (unexpected) behaviour, and 2) is the correct design to first persist my Tags and then the Item?